# I want to do something with jquery when the page is ready (like $(window).ready()) but it seems it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery to change the content of my html page according to the page width. Then when the page is ready (using `$(document).ready(function({\\there is some code here!}));`) I want to call some functions.
I want to eliminate my main menu when the page width is small (less than 835px) and put something else in its place. Also page resizing is important for this goal. I use this code to do this:

```js
function deleteMainMenu(){ 
 var width = $(window).width();
 if(width <= 835){  
  $("#main-menu").empty();  
  $("#main-menu").append('add some html code here');
  $("#logo").attr('class', 'col-xs-6');
  $("#main-menu").attr('class', 'col-xs-6');

 }
 else{
  $("#logo").attr('class', 'col-sm-2');
  $("#main-menu").attr('class', 'col-sm-10');
  $("#main-menu").empty();
  $("#main-menu:empty").append('reset my old html code');
 }
}
```

I call these functions by this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
    deleteMainMenu();
});

$( window ).resize(function(){
    deleteMainMenu();
});
```

My code works fine when I resize the page, but when I initialize the page width to less than 835px and then reload the page, nothing happens!

I tested it in my phone and it seemed that nothing happened, but when you scroll, suddenly functions are going to perform.

What should I do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try w3.css. With it you do not have to use JS to manipulate some parts of the DOM.

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/jpng7gug/. Is the issue that the ready handler isn't running, or is something else going on?

Comment: for the future - you can shorten `$(document).ready(function() { /* code */)` to just `$(function() { /* code */)` and also you can shorten `$(function() { deleteMainMenu(); });` to just `$(deleteMainMenu)`,

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't think javascript is the way to go here. CSS has some pretty sweet options for these situations.

**Bootstrap**

Looking at your classes (col-xs-6) it looks like you're using bootstrap. 
Bootstrap has got some pretty nice features especially for this kind of thing.
Have a look at [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) for the responsive utilities.

**Non bootstrap**

If you don't want to use the bootstrap utilities, you could do something like this:

Create the 2 menu's (.menu_big and .menu_small) and show/hide them using mediaqueries.

```
.menu_big{
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 835px) {
  .menu_small{
    display: none;
  }
  .menu_big{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/ksb5hrw2/)